# location.reload() with no parameters

Tags: jquery

I have the below code.

```
<button id="RefreshMe">Refresh Page</button>
<script>
jQuery('#PageRefresh').click(function() {
    location.reload();
});
</script>
```

This works fine however my page has some hidden values in a form so instead of reloading www.example.com it reloads www.example.com?a=111 etc which is causing an error as the uri is to big.  I want the user to go back to www.example.com rather than www.example.com?a=111 what else needs to be added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.location = document.location.replace(/[\?].*/,'');
```

Answer (score 1):

A better answer is this:

```
  history.pushState({}, 'title', '/');
```

This will refresh the page with no params and no path (basically your home page).  But let's say you have a non-home page, such as:

```
yoursite.com/pricing?myparam=shazam
```

If you want to just remove the param, you'd do this:

```
history.pushState({}, 'title', '/pricing');
```

And you'd end up with this:

```
yoursite.com/pricing
```